# Flutter/Dart: How to perform Synchronization

Tags: flutter, dart

The question says itself, here I have a list which calling `write` method a couple of times but it's not providing output sequentially.

```
void main() {
   List<int> list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
   write(list);
   write(list);
}
```

`write` functions takes the List and print the values in the delay of 1 millisecond

```
write(List<int> values) async {
  for (int value in values) {
    await Future.delayed(new Duration(microseconds: 1));
    print(value);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
I/flutter (21092): 1
I/flutter (21092): 1
I/flutter (21092): 2
I/flutter (21092): 2
I/flutter (21092): 3
I/flutter (21092): 3
I/flutter (21092): 4
I/flutter (21092): 4
```

**Expected Output:**

```
I/flutter (21092): 1
I/flutter (21092): 2
I/flutter (21092): 3
I/flutter (21092): 4
I/flutter (21092): 1
I/flutter (21092): 2
I/flutter (21092): 3
I/flutter (21092): 4
```

Comment: did you try putting `await` before each of your calls to `write`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To Achieve this use `synchronized` lib

**Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:**

```
dependencies:
  synchronized: ^2.2.0+2
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
write(List<int> values) async {
  var lock = Lock();
  for (int value in values) {
    lock.synchronized(() {
      Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 2));
    });
    print(value);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
I/flutter (21092): 1
I/flutter (21092): 2
I/flutter (21092): 3
I/flutter (21092): 4
I/flutter (21092): 1
I/flutter (21092): 2
I/flutter (21092): 3
I/flutter (21092): 4
```

**Note:** `synchronized` block will run all the list first then only allowed to enter second one.

Comment: There is no reason to downvote this, as it gives another way of using syncronization.

Comment: Could you please explain why you are not simply awaiting the Futures here? As @chazmat mentioned. It's not clear to me how using a lock is a better approach here.

Comment: Could you explain why you are not simply using`await write();await write`?

Comment: The purpose of what he is demonstrating is how to prevent reentry into a region while some functionality is being performed. Lets say you had a method which gets hit from multiple sources, and sets a 'lastChecked' valued at the end of the block, and checks how long has elapsed since the lastChecked at the start. If caller A, hits the block and is running something async, not yet setting lastChecked, and caller B enters, B won't see lastChecked as having happened yet because the two blocks are running concurrently.

Comment: This is really wrong usage of the lock. The lock isn't really doing anything here. Firstly because you are creating separate locks for each call to `write`. And also you will see that the future delay doesn't even wait 2 seconds or anything, because you aren't doing any `await`. The only reason it has the right result is because of this. The right way would be to create a `Lock` outside the method and put the entire body of the function in `lock.synchronized`-

Answer (score 5):

Just "await" the first write function

```
void main() async {
     List<int> list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
     await write(list);
     write(list);
 }
```